# How to add an component with type IResolvable to CfnImageRecipe CDK resource?

Tags: typescript, amazon-web-services, aws-cdk

I'm seeing this error: `error TS2322: Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'ComponentConfigurationProperty | IResolvable'`
when I try to create a CfnImageRecipe with the CDK.

Here's the code:

```
    const imageRecipe = new imagebuilder.CfnImageRecipe(this, 'MediaRecipe', {
      name: 'MediaRecipe',
      components: ["arn:aws:imagebuilder:us-west-1:aws:component/amazon-cloudwatch-agent-linux/1.0.0"],
      parentImage: 'centos:latest',
      version: '1.0.0',
      workingDirectory: '/tmp'
    });
```

clearly it isn't going to accept a sting, I just can't find any **decent** documentation on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to work for me (it synths at least).

```
import * as cdk from '@aws-cdk/core';
import {CfnImageRecipe} from '@aws-cdk/aws-imagebuilder';

export class TmpStack extends cdk.Stack {
  constructor(scope: cdk.Construct, id: string, props?: cdk.StackProps) {
    super(scope, id, props);

    new CfnImageRecipe(this, 'example-id', {
      name: 'MediaRecipe',
      components: [
        { 
          componentArn:"arn:aws:imagebuilder:us-west-1:aws:component/amazon-cloudwatch-agent-linux/1.0.0"
        }
      ],
      parentImage: 'centos:latest',
      version: '1.0.0',
      workingDirectory: '/tmp'
    });
  }
}
```

What IDE are you using? I'm using WebStorm and in Typescript a lot of this is code hinted for you. It might make it a little easier to explore.

Comment: I'm using VScode - but your solution worked, thank you

Comment: I do however, see this: `The provided parent image must be either an EC2 AMI Id or a valid Image Builder Image Arn.` but in the console, it gives an option to pull from dockerhub, so i'd like to be able to pull base image from dockerhub, then version that image with our customizations in ecr